# Save a file to the local server that has a force download header

Tags: php, header

I am trying to "copy" a file from a remote server that is being forced to download through the browser. The headers that the remote file outputs are as follows:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2011 00:19:21 GMT
Content-Type: application/txt
Content-Length: 170783
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Mar 2011 00:00:43 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="titles.txt"
Expires: Tue, 01 Mar 2011 02:19:21 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes

I need some sort of way to override the attachment Content-Disposition so that php can copy the file to the local server. Either that, or some other way of downloading the file from the remote server into the local.

The file to download is a simple text file which would normally be displayed in the browser however I need PHP to "download" it locally as a sort of cache.

I've looked around this site but none of the attempts I've found worked >_<

Any suggestions?!

Thanks in advance,
ShadowPuppet

Comment: the fact that the browser sends content-disposition doesn't block you to get the data anyway lol

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow. You want a server to save a file, but its using the browser??
The following should do what you're after

$file = 'www.exmple.com/mytext.txt';

// Open the file to get existing content

$current = file_get_contents($file);

// Write the contents back to the file

file_put_contents("user/path/to/file/mytext.txt", $current);

Comment: No, see... the file is on a remote server and it's outputting a header that is forcing the browser to display the save as dialog when you visit the url. I need it to output in the window instead of showing that dialog

Comment: Do you want copy this damn remote file? JUST READ IT normally! DOH

Answer (score 0):

At everyone else `file_get_contents` works even if the server sends content-disposition.

Check your PHP version and its bugs.

Comment: Version 5.2.14 and I have no idea but it does not work for this site... perhaps there is some other protection behind it? Is there a way to explicitly deny php from fetching it?

Comment: the only "protection" they can add is to check the request headers. Try adding an IE like User-Agent a Referer coming from their website or something like that

Comment: I would add too: stealing files and contents from other website isn't legal

Comment: LOL I'm not stealing the content. It's publicly downloadable... I just need PHP to get it.